# Not able to get value of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In edit mode, the textbox is rendered as:

```
<input value="10/05/2017" name="purchasedate" id="purchasedate" class="form-control required valid" aria-required="true" type="text">
```

In jQuery I am trying to fetch:

```
function validateform(){
   var purchasedate = $("#purchasedate").val().trim();
   alert(purchasedate);
   if(!checkValidDate(purchasedate)){
     displayDateErrorMessage("Purchase Date");
     return false;
   }       
}
```

It is displayed as blank!

Please help !

Comment: Code should work. Show where and how are you using the above code?

Comment: Code works just fine

Comment: but it is not working and also if we change the value of textbox, it is displayed as blank

Comment: Call this code inside a function on a button click or onblur once.

Comment: I think you missed $(document).ready(function(){}); for you script part

Comment: Code is working fine. Can you please check console error and share that?

Comment: Code is working fine.Do you have any error in browser console?\

Comment: use: text="something" inside input tag and try

Comment: updated my question

Comment: What is displaying as blank. Text box value in alert or displayDateErrorMessage function call?

Comment: @user2179026  where did you called your function?

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$('#elementid').attr('value');
```

Comment: But dont know why are you thanking for posting answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your function as callback to `$(document).ready()`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var purchasedate = $("#purchasedate").val().trim();
  alert(purchasedate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="10/05/2017" name="purchasedate" id="purchasedate" class="form-control required valid" aria-required="true" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

write **onChange** in textbox

```
<input onChange="validateform()" value="10/05/2017" name="purchasedate" id="purchasedate" class="form-control required valid" aria-required="true" type="text">
```